# Print the callsite of all calls to Debug.Write()

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Is there any way to print the callsite (source-file and linenumber) of **all** calls to Debug.Write() in the debug-output of a c#-project?

**Background:**

I'am new to a very old and big project, so I started to run the application in debug-mode. At some points in the app, that I'am interested in, the debug-ouput is writing some meaningless lines like:

```
object
object
object
```

I thought it would be nice if I could configure the Debug-class or give it some kind of callback to take the stackframe and print the callsite in front of the debug-output like this:

```
SomeClass.cs[45]: object
SomeClass.cs[45]: object
SomeClass.cs[45]: object
```

Comment: Are you able to replace all those calls with calls to a new method which captures the caller info and adds it to the message?

Comment: @Jon: Yes, I could replace all calls with R#, but it will take more than 1h to complete. But the project is still under active development, so I have to keep this changes in my workingcopy or convice the other devs, that this is a good idea ;)

Comment: I suspect if you show them the clearer output, that would probably convince them fairly quickly...

Comment: If all your code is in the same namespace, you *may* be able to add another class to that namespace called `Debug` with a `Write` method and make the refactoring simpler that way. I'd have to check, but I have a sneaking suspicion that class names in the current namespace (or a "parent" namespace) take priority over those imported with using directives. You could then make R# refactor the calls in one go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Jon Skeets suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32966017/print-the-callsite-of-all-calls-to-debug-write/32971123#comment53757848_32966017) I implemented a Degub class in the root-namespace like the following:

```
public static class Debug
{
    public static void WriteLine(string str)
    {
        var sf = new StackFrame(1,true);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("{0}({1}): {2}",
            Path.GetFileName(sf.GetFileName()),
            sf.GetFileLineNumber(),
            str
        );
    }
}
```

It seems like the compiler is prefering this one over the one defined in the using clause. But careful:

- every *used* Member of the original Debug-class must be implemented (`Listeners` and overloads of `Write()` and `WriteLine()` for example) - otherwise the build fails.
- our Solution consists of several cs-projects with different namespaces. So I had to copy this Debug class too all root-namespaces

All in all: I'm happy with this solution - Thanks!